# gzip, deflate decompress php

Tags: php, gzip, deflate

I have an encoded string, how do I decode it

> eNpTNXdSNTJKLSrKLwLSqsaOJUWlqapGzkBOSmpxMlQQSKYlZuakpqgaGSSWlmTkF2VWJZZk5ueBpM1dALkhFLk=

gzdecode, gzinflate, zlib_decode output false

[on this site it stands for as it should be](https://www.multiutil.com/gzip-to-text-decompress/)

Comment: `base64_decode` first, `gzuncompress` second. https://3v4l.org/KQStN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of layers to decode here:

```
$result = json_decode(urldecode(zlib_decode(base64_decode($str))), true);
```

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [error] => 1
    [descr] => failed authorization
)
```